# Is there any alternative to Java properties for keeping tree-like data?

Tags: java

I have 3 item data that I should keep on remote PC. Let it be: ID, login, password.
If there're only 2 items, Java property will suit me great, but I have some sort of tree. It is impossible to install any DB on that machine, so the variant with DB usage is declined at once.

Do we have any alternative to Java properties to solve this task?

P.S> Almost forgot, there's only JRE on remote PC and I have no way to install JDK there.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: How about storing it as `ID=login:password` and then parsing it later?

Comment: @adarshr Hm, where can I read about this form and its usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using of [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) instead

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep a tree of properties, I would suggest XML.

Comment: Why the downvote? From the faq: "Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong"